# Facebook share don't show title and picture from article

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I created a draft for a future blog and for testing the Facebook share function.

http://spritzi.com/blog/test/skull2.htm

When I hit the share button it doesn't show the article title and pics but the old icon and old description that I don't use any more. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook caches some data like the images. If you updated something and don't want to wait, you could manually trigger an update via: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks I deleted the images and now it works. Even if I am not shure to know really why